# Fast easy refactoring in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I have a large project that is quite a mess.  There's God classes, poor variable naming, poor indentation and spacing...among other issues.

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to make marketable improvements to such a project.  In Visual Studio 2010 CTRL + K and CTRL + D gives me fast code cleanup.  Organize usings takes out unused namespaces.  But, both only seem to work on 1 page.  Can I apply these changes to a project?  Are there any similar cleanup techniques or free and reliable 3rd party addons?

Comment: What language are you using ? Visual Studio let you work with a plethora of languages, and refactoring tools and techniques are often highly dependent on wich language you are using. If you are using C#, there are a lot of details about 3rd parties in related questions on SO (and it`s generally http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ that comes out).

Comment: @Matthieu - C#.  its marked in my tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One third party extension that I use that is **free** is [DevExpress' Coderush Xpress](http://go.devexpress.com/CodeRushX.aspx) (For C# and VB), which is the free edition of their full product.  The great thing about this is that the express edition still lets you add CodeRush plugins to it (in addition to several project-wide refactoring options), which opens you up to a ton more options than just the Visual Studio Plugins.

[Here is a huge list of the plugins available for CR Xpress](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/PluginResources).

Answer (score 7):

Try out [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)-- it can do what you're looking for.

Comment: Resharper can even clean-out the whole project or even the whole solution according to pre-defined rules. It is for sure what you are looking for

Comment: The question asks for a free addon. It may be worth saying that R# is commercial, *but* by using the trial period one can certainly get the codebase cleaned up for free (and you may end up liking R# so much that you end up buying instead of uninstalling it after the trial - it's like coding on drugs or so, you get addicted ;) ).

Comment: @Matt Cofer - I have used the trial version of Resharper. It is nice, but if the company won't pay for it, I am hesitant to shell out my own cash.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/default.asp) for quite some time, and I found it very useful.  It is not free, and it may not automate the sweeping changes you seem to be looking for, but it makes simple refactoring much easier.

P.S. I have been using it for C++, not C#.  But if anything, I would assume that it would have more capabilities for C#.